# GCP - Can't see active billing accounts information even though I have Billing Account Administrator role

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In `Google Cloud Platform`.

I have `Owner + Billing Account Administrator` roles in the organization level.
I still can't see any information about the billing.

What am I missing?

> You don’t have permission to list projects for this billing account."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In enterprise organization, If you are getting "You don’t have permission to list projects for this billing account."
Check policy permission might be it is blocked with iam policy.

Billing Account Viewer (roles/billing.viewer) is more then enough to view the billing.
[image: Billing Account]

Answer (score 4):

According to [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/job-functions/billing#small_company_configuring_billing_permissions), your role `Billing Account Administrator` can:

> The Billing Account Administrator role allows the office manager and the CEO to manage payments and invoices without granting them the permission to view the project contents.

Try getting also the `Billing Account Viewer`:

> The Billing Account Viewer role allows the developers to view the expenses for a billing account.

Comment: @EilonA If this answer was helpful to you, you can click on the checkmark icon to accept the answer.  This can help future users who are having the same issue.